# Memory leak when instantiating many Strings

Tags: java, memory-leaks

**UPDATE2:**
Originally this issue was confounded with MongoDB and Jackson, but it's actually reproducible simply by making a lot of `Strings`.

The problem is that when creating many small `String`s, about 10% of the JVM memory appears to be permanently lost. This only occurs after creating the strings three times, and doesn't appear to occur again.

This appears to be either a Java 'feature' or a bug.

**UPDATE3:** The JVM is started with `-Xms3000m`.

**UPDATE4:** Maybe something to do with [string interning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestMemLeak {

    public static String TEXT100 = "";
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TEXT100 += "aaaaabbbbb";
        }
    }
    public static String TEXT1000 = "";
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            TEXT1000 += TEXT100;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i: Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)) {
            System.out.println("---------- " + i + " ------------");
            System.gc();
            try {
                makeStrings();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<String> makeStrings() throws Exception {
        printMem("*** start ***");
        List<String> l= new LinkedList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
            l.add("" + TEXT1000);
        }
        printMem("*** end ***");
        return l;
    }

    public static void printMem(String s) {
        System.out.println(s);
        System.out.println("free mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        System.out.println(" max mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
        System.out.println(" ttl mem: " + Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory());
    }
}
```

Output below. Note that in the third loop the available mem permanently drops. This does not occur in further loops.

```
---------- 1 ------------
*** start ***
free mem: 2967193768
 max mem: 3014656000
 ttl mem: 3014656000
*** end ***
free mem: 937879792
 max mem: 3014656000
 ttl mem: 3014656000
---------- 2 ------------
*** start ***
free mem: 2998712752
 max mem: 3014656000
 ttl mem: 3014656000
*** end ***
free mem: 938854128
 max mem: 3014656000
 ttl mem: 3014656000
---------- 3 ------------
*** start ***
free mem: 2998619464
 max mem: 3014656000
 ttl mem: 3014656000
*** end ***
free mem: 729745856
 max mem: 2796224512
 ttl mem: 2796224512
---------- 4 ------------
*** start ***
free mem: 2788946120
 max mem: 2796224512
 ttl mem: 2796224512
*** end ***
free mem: 726522240
 max mem: 2796224512
 ttl mem: 2796224512
```

Java: 1.7_25

Comment: From what I understand from you problem the reason lies in the fact that `Strings` are immutable in java. When you do `TEXT1000 += TEXT100` a new `String` is created every time.

Comment: @Prateek Right, but those strings created by the line in your comment are created before the memory loss and since no references are retained will be garbage collected. The strings in the makeStrings() function are retained in memory, but I don't see any reason that should cause a reduction of the overall heap space. Free mem will obviously go down, but max and ttl should not.

Comment: I'm no JVM expert, but… (a) Yes, probably a feature not a bug, due to string interning or the retention of actively-used objects. (b) You did not specify what Java implementation and host platform you ran on. Oracle's JVM? On a Mac, Linux? (c) If Oracle's JVM, try the latest version of Java 7 (Update 45). Oracle has been making many changes to the JVM in the lifecycle of Java 7 as they merge the best of both [HotSpot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HotSpot) and [JRockit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRockit). (d) For fun, perhaps you should try Java 8.

Comment: Can't explain it (interning should not be involved), but it's not a bug.  GC does not have to adhere to any formula, and, in fact, `System.gc()` doesn't even have to do anything.

Comment: @HotLicks yep, since in J7 string interning is stored in the heap, can't be interning related.

Comment: @elhefe - Besides, there's nothing in the above code that would cause interning.